# Arduino DNS on local

Tags: arduino, ethernet

How do I reference the address of the DNS serverIP, subnetIP, gatewayIP ?

As you can see from teh code below, I have tried but all I geet is the following error,

"class EthernetClass has no member called subnet".

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Network configuration
// Note : DNS server, gateway and subnet are optional.

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };  

//  The IP address of Arduino Ethernet shield.
IPAddress myLocalIP(192, 168, 100, 2);

// The DNS server IP.
IPAddress dnsServer(192, 168, 100, 1);

// The router's gateway IP address.
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);

// the subnet:
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, myLocalIP, subnet);    // Initialize the ethernet device
//  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dnServer, gateway, subnet);

  Serial.print("Local IP = ");  // Print out the IP address of the shield.
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  Serial.print("DNS Address = ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.IPAddress.subnet() );
}  // End setup.

void loop()
{

}  // End loop.
```

Wallek876, Thank you for the info.

I have added the others as well, namely subnetMask, gatewayIP however when I used the documented method (as per your link) to print the MAC address - namely - Ethernet.MACAddress(macBuffer); I got an error.

The documented code - (copied from the documentation) is as follows;

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip(10, 0, 0, 177);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  byte macBuffer[6];  // create a buffer to hold the MAC address
  Ethernet.MACAddress(macBuffer); // fill the buffer
  Serial.print("The MAC address is: ");
  for (byte octet = 0; octet < 6; octet++) {
    Serial.print(macBuffer[octet], HEX);
    if (octet < 5) {
      Serial.print('-');
    }
  }
}

void loop () {}
```

The error being on line Ethernet.MACAddress(macBuffer);
MACAddress not defined.

I tried several other solutions all to no avail - so some suggetions would be greatefully received.

Comment: I can't reproduce the second error, the code looks ok as you have it, not sure what can be the cause.

Comment: Wallek876, Did you try compiling the code?  When I compiled the code the compiler complained that there was no  format for MAC Address.  I looked in the source code of ethernet.h and ther eis no definition specification for MACAddress.

Comment: Can you please try to compilie the code (on the Arduino UNO) and see if it works for you?  If it does, can you please send me the the ethernet.h file that contains the definition etc.

Comment: I compiled it indeed, no errors, [ethernet.h](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Ethernet) is the default that comes with the arduino IDE, maybe you have an older version, try to update it with the library manager

Comment: Wallek876,  Thank you for your suggestion - I have updated file ethernet.h to version 2.0 and all works - much appreciated

Comment: Wallek876, How do I now end this and give you credit successfully answering my question?